# Can't get location or name from Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

So I have this code (obviously purposely hiding the tokens)

```
import tweepy
consumerkey=''
consumerkeysecret=''
bearer=''
access=''
access_secret=''
auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler(consumerkey, consumerkeysecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
tweet='1314271994054152192'
status = api.get_status(tweet,tweet_mode='extended')
print(status.screen_name)
print(status.location)
```

I'm learning Tweepy and so I used a tweet from Obama to test the features of the API. For whatever reason, I can't get the screen name or location for the tweet, as it says 'Status' object has no attribute 'location'. When I look at the json from printing out all the information about the tweet, both 'location' and 'screen_name' are in there and have text associated with it. How can I get this information?

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the User object inside the Status object:

```
    print(status.user.screen_name)
    print(status.user.location)
```